# Using PDFKIT to generate PDF using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, pdfkit

I wrote a node.js server to generate and PDF using pdfkit and return it without saving to a file:

```
var http = require('http');
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');

var server = http.createServer();

server.on('request', function(request, response) {
    console.log('request - ' + new Date());
    buildReport(request, response);
});

server.listen(3000);

console.log('Servidor iniciado em localhost:3000. Ctrl+C para encerrar…');

function buildReport(request, response) {
    var PDFDoc = new PDFDocument();

    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    });

    PDFDoc.pipe(response);

    PDFDoc.font('fonts/DroidSans.ttf')
          .fontSize(25)
          .text('Some text with an embedded font!', 100, 100);

    // Finalize PDF file
    PDFDoc.end();
}
```

If I go to the browser and type `http:\\localhost:3000` it works fine. The PDF appears on the browser window.

But the problem is that I have to put the result of this request inside an iframe. This next line works:

```
$('#iframe').attr('src', 'http://localhost:3000');
```

But since I have to pass parameters to the server I'm using ajax and then it does not work. On the client side I have:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000',
    data: {
        reportData: reportData,
        reportMetadata: reportMetadata,
        reportLogo: reportLogo
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    $('#iframe').attr('src', data);
});
```

but this does not work. I tried alter the done function to:

```
.done(function(data) {
    var PDFOutput = 'data:application/pdf;charset=UTF-8,'+data;
    $('#iframe').attr('src', PDFOutput);
});
```

but it does not work either...

The value returned to the data variable inside `done` function is a string that starts with:

```
"%PDF-1.3 %���� 5 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 1 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 612 792] /Contents 3 0 R /Resources 4 0 R >> endobj 4 0 obj << /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI] /Font << /F2 6 0 R >> >> endobj 7 0 obj << /Producer (PDFKit) /Creator (PDFKit) /CreationDate (D:20151010210841Z) >> endobj 9 0 obj << /Type /FontDesc (...)
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do something like that.

In your `done` function, `data` contains the body of your PDF file.

An iframe is supposed to load content from an url, so with your JQuery, just change the `src` attribute like this :

```
$('#iframe').attr('src', 'http://localhost:3000?reportData='+reportData+'& reportMetadata='+reportMetadata+'&reportLogo='+reportLogo);
```

As you can't `POST` data to an iframe (not by a clean way) you will have to use `GET` parameters. Maybe the datas your are passing are to heavy to be passed by `GET` so you will have to find an another way...

Comment: Thanks Raphael... This solution works, but I was wondering, in fact, if I can't transform the body of my PDF to an object URL like `data:application/PDF;base64,AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA....`

Comment: I don't think it would be possible because a PDF file is something huge which can exceed the URL length limit (http://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/3212099). Also it would be a performance-killer doing that.